# Creating the effect of sprites jumping in and out of objects

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I was trying to achieve the following functionality and wanted to ask for some help:

There are n barrels on the screen.

Randomly, a monster will pop up out of the barrel, and then go back down. I got this working, but I want to make a revision where sometimes instead of going up/down, a monster will jump out of the barrel along an arc, and land somewhere on the ground nearby. After some time, he will jump back and follow the path in reverse back into the barrel.

My original code workedby simply created a barrel i.e. addChild(barrel) to the scene, added a cropping node over it i.e. addChild(croppingNode) where croppingNode's position is over the barrel, and then add the monster to the cropping node as a child (croppingNode.addchild(monster))

This worked perfectly - the monsters come up, and then slide back down and the node hides their lower half so they appear to have went back inside the barrel.

My revision was to have a monster randomly jump out of the barrel on an angle and land on the ground, but the problem is because the monster is added to the cropping node, it is clipped if I try to move it outside the bounds of a cropping node.

If I add the monster outside of the cropping node, I believe he will no longer be cropped, correct?

What would be a way to achieve something like this? Use a larger cropping node image that is larger than the barrel and accounts for his arc onto the ground?

Thanks!

Comment: when the monster is ready to jump out of the barrel, use moveToParent to move the monster to the scene

Comment: hmm I never thought about that. Is it possible you could elaborate for me? that sounds very hopeful! Is the idea i'm going to move the sprite "up" from the cropping node and onto the entire scene so it doesn't operate in the confines of the node? What about if I want to add it back to the cropping node after? How can I move it back?

Comment: ... you use moveToParent to move it back to the node of your choice

Comment: Ok thought so, just wanted to make sure. :)  I'll try this and let everyone know

Comment: It would be helpful if you show a visual example. Using colored rects. There are some other techniques that can be done potentially.

Comment: Did you consider setting the zPositions of the barrels and monsters, so that the monsters appear behind the barrels instead of using crop nodes? According to the docs, "Use clipping and effect nodes sparingly. Both are very powerful, but can be [computationally] expensive..."

Comment: @0x141E, he would have to use zPosition regardless, I think he is clipping so that the monsters toes do not hang outside the barrel